# Jquery - Bootstrap table, to show more results with button or link

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I am using bootstrap table for to load datas.
[Bootstrap table](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/)

I have the next table html:

[image]

When I click on the "More results" link, the pagination of the table occurs, how could do it?

This is the html code:

```
<table id="table" class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-field="field1">Title1</th>
        <th data-field="field2">Title2</th>
        <th data-field="field3">Title3</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody></tbody>
<tfoot>
<tr>
        <td colspan="6"><a href="#">...More results...</a></td>
</tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

This is the js code:

```
 // Loading json in talbe
      $("#table").bootstrapTable({
          formatNoMatches: function () {
              return 'No records';
          },
          //Assigning data to table docs
          data: data,
          pagination: true,
          pageSize: 10
      });
```

This is css code:

```
.fixed-table-loading, .fixed-table-pagination {
    display: none !important;
}
```

This is the json:

```
var data = [
{
"field1": "Dato1",
"field2": "Dato2",
"field3": "Dato3"
},
{
"field1": "Dato1",
"field2": "Dato2",
"field3": "Dato3"
},
{
"field1": "Dato1",
"field2": "Dato2",
"field3": "Dato3"
}
];
```

And only would show the button "More results" if we have more than 10 results.

Thanks,

Comment: I have resolved, to hide the button if the returned records are more than ten with: var countRowsTable = Object.keys (data) .length; but I still have pending the pagination with the same button, any idea?

Comment: I have solved everything using jquery and the page-change.bs.table event, this is closed